# i need get all value in in one column , like my picture , i write foreach loop for that but only respond one record in my column ? what can i do?

Tags: c#, foreach, datatables

```
DataTable checkbag=(DataTable)Session["bag"];                 
foreach(DataRow row in checkbag.Rows)  
{
    if(row["id"].ToString()==e.CommandArgument.ToString()  
    {
       Response.Redirect("mybag.aspx");
       break;
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I usually use this.  Not sure if answer will be different

```
            foreach(DataRow row in checkbag.AsEnumerable())  
            {
                if(row.Field<string>("id")  == e.CommandArgument.ToString())  
                {
                   Response.Redirect("mybag.aspx");
                   break;
                }
            }
```